# Handling a number of simultaneous measurements in Extended Kalman Filter?

Tags: kalman-filters, sensor

If I have a number of sensors whose measurements arrive at the same time - how can I handle them properly in the Kalman filter?

P.S.
The measurements are not necessarily taken at the same time but I only receive them batched together.

Answer (score 1):

If your measurements are batch, so is your filter.

You can do a number of things.

You can sequence your measurements in natural order and update the filter for each.

You can do the previous and then approach the problem as a fixed lag smoother.

There is a literature on out of sequence and delayed updating as well, like:

> Ensemble Kalman filter for multisensor fusion with multistep delayed
>   measurements Sirichai Pornsarayouth; Masaki Yamakita
>
> 2011 Aerospace Conference Year: 2011 Pages: 1 - 10 Cited by: Papers
>   (1) IEEE Conferences